# Why does my code output the same dict pairs onto a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text, with-statement

(Python 3.9)

So I made a simple program that logs usernames and password in a dict(Yes I know storing passwords as plaintext is always a bad idea but I'm learning about dicts and writing to files, not databases and encryption) and prints them onto a text file.

But here's the problem.
I type in the username and password.
That gets saved to a **dict**. A **for loop** then writes each **k, v** to the text file within my with statement and my **dict** gets printed onto the terminal showing that the **k, v** I  just entered are indeed in the dictionary.

I do this process again, my new set of **k, v's** are once again stored in my **dict** along with the first pairs from before but when I go and check the file that it wrote to, instead of printing the new dictionary pair, it's printed the same ones from before.

Run the program and you'll see what I mean. What's happening here? Clearly it has to do with something in my for loop.

```
while True:
user = input("Enter username: ")
if user not in store:
    password = input("Enter password: ")
    store[user] = password

    with open('userLog.txt', 'a') as userLog:
        for k, v in store.items():
            str_keys = str(k)
            str_values = str(v)
            userPass = f"Username: {k} | Password: {v} \n"
            userLog.write(userPass)
            print(store)
            break

else:
    print('Username Taken!')
    continue
```

Comment: Your for loop only runs once because you have a break statement. Do you want to write the entire store each time? If so, remove the break statement. Do you only want to add the new user / pass pair? Then you don't need a for loop, just write `user` and `password` into the file.

Comment: Could you write that as an answer with some code? I'm a visual learner samurai

Comment: I didn't notice your name until l I saw "samurai"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @alex, this is what I was looking for. My problem was the for loop along with the break statement. Turns out I don't even need a for loop.

```
 store = {}

while True:
    user = input("Enter username: ")
    if user not in store:
        password = input("Enter password: ")
        store[user] = password

        with open('userLog.txt', 'a') as userLog:
            userLog.write(f"Username: {user} | Password: {password} \n")

    else:
        print('Username Taken!')
        continue
```

Comment: "wake the frick up samurai, you have a `for` loop to burn",

Comment: Great, note that you don't need the `continue` statement if you have nothing else in this while loop.